# Can we know if a openUrl come from the widget that we created?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget, widgetkit

I created a new iOS widget based by one of my iOS application witch is using UIKit.

I using swiftUI to create the widget and everything is fine.

So I trying to finish it with a Url deeplink from this widget.
The code is looks like this

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text(entry.title).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    }
    .widgetURL(URL(string: "myscheme://deeplink/listing?pid=widget_init")!)
}
```

widgetURL works fine and I received the url from my `AppDelegate`

```
public func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool
```

The question is I just get the url but everything in options is nil.
Does someone know why the bundle id that should be inside options now is nil?

I want know if the deeplink is come from my widget. Or if there's some other way can get it?

Comment: Register unique url scheme or give unique url query parameters when open from widget and use that as indicator.

Comment: Thanks this is the way like I did just now, add a unique url query parameters. But the parameters also can be used in every app not only in my widget. I'm going to tracking this. So if possible I want more correct information.